# Is $\sqrt 7$ a sum of roots of unity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, roots-of-unity, cyclotomic-fields

Let $a_1,\dots,a_n$ and $b_1,\dots,b_n$ be two sequences of rational numbers.

> Is it possible that $\sqrt 7 = \sum_{m=1}^{n} a_m (-1)^{b_m}$?
> Is it possible that $\sqrt{17}$ = $\sum_{m=1}^{n} a_m (-1)^{b_m}$?

How to prove or disprove these ?

Comment: Wait: What does this have to do with representation-theory?

Comment: I don't think your question accurately reflects the title. You use $n$ to index your sets and also as the size of the sets, this is confusing. Also don't you want the $a_k$ to be roots of unity, not rationals?

Comment: @DylanYott The roots of unity (confusingly, I agree) are actually the other terms; they're the $(-1)^{b_m}$ factors in those sums.  (Remember, $b_m$ is a rational, not an integer, so these are complex values)

Comment: To extend Dylan's point slightly, though, the expression $(-1)^{b_m}$ is confusing because it requires a canonical choice of branch for the (implicit) logarithm; it would be _much_ better to write those terms as $e^{2m\pi i/n}$, or $\zeta^m$ in terms of a canonical root of unity $\zeta=e^{2\pi i/n}$, as Jyrki does in their answer.

Comment: You may be interested in this closely related [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/279713/462).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Square roots of integers and cyclotomic fields](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/282757/square-roots-of-integers-and-cyclotomic-fields)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Let $\zeta=e^{2\pi i/7}$. We know that
$$
1+\zeta+\zeta^2+\cdots+\zeta^6=0.
$$
Let
$$
S=\zeta+\zeta^2+\zeta^4.
$$
Then by squaring we get
$$
S^2=\zeta^2+\zeta^4+\zeta^8+2\zeta^3+2\zeta^5+2\zeta^6.
$$
Observe that $\zeta^8=\zeta$.
Subtract the above equation multiplied by two from this to get
$$
S^2=-2-\zeta-\zeta^2-\zeta^4=-2-S.
$$
Let $M=2S+1$. Then
$$
M^2=4S^2+4S+1=4(-2-S)+4S+1=-7.
$$
Therefore $M=\pm i\sqrt7$, and you can surely construct a sum of the required type from this.

The above recipe works for all primes $p$ instead of $p=7$ as long as you follow the rule that the exponents of $\zeta$ (here $1,2,4$) are the quadratic residues modulo $p$ (so you need $(p-1)/2$ terms in the sum $S$). Whether you get $+p$ or $-p$ as the square depends on the residue class of $p$ modulo $4$.

Look up [Gauss' sums](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_Gauss_sum) for details of the general case.

Comment: So, you are saying $i\sqrt{p}\in \mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$ for any primitive $p$ th root $\zeta$..

Comment: Almost but not quite, @Praphulla. A closer examination reveals that $\sqrt p\in\Bbb{Q}(\zeta)$, if $p\equiv1\pmod4$ and $i\sqrt p\in\Bbb{Q}(\zeta)$, if $p\equiv 3\pmod4$. By Galois theory $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta)$ has a unique quadratic subfield so we have just found it! Here $p$ is an odd prime number.

Answer (score 18):

Let $d$ be an integer. The field extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d}) / \mathbb{Q}$ is a abelian extension, and therefore it is a subextension of a cyclotomic field extension $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta) / \mathbb{Q}$ where $\zeta$ is some root of unity. Thus, $\sqrt{d} \in \mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$, that is, $\sqrt{d}$ is a rational function of $\zeta$.

Since $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)/\mathbb{Q}$ is an algebraic extension, this further means that $\sqrt{d}$ is a polynomial in $\zeta$ with rational coefficients, which is easy to put into the form you seek.

In fact, because $\sqrt{d}$ is an algebraic integer, it must lie in $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$, we can even select the $a_m$ to be integers. In fact, we can even arrange to have all of the $a_m$ be equal to 1, if we allow roots of unity to be repeated in the sum.

Comment: Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker%E2%80%93Weber_theorem

Comment: Just to be clear, this also implies that $\sqrt d$ can be represented as $\sum a_m\cdot 1^{b_m}$ for *integer* $a_m$, by multiplying through by the common denominator, correct?

Comment: @MJD: Yes, because the ring of integers in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$ is $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$, and $\sqrt{d}$ is an algebraic integer. (I don't follow your recipe)

Answer (score 3):

The square root of any number $n$, can be derived from the span of chords of a polygon $2n$, and $n$ if $4|n-1$.  Correspondingly, since the cords can be derived from cyclotomic roots of $1$ (ie numbers of the form $cis(\pi m/n)$ where $0<m<2n$, then all such square roots can be so derived.

One approach to solving this sort of equation, is to look for a primitive root.  For $13$, we might note that $2$ is a primitive root.  We then create a power-series of $2$, modulo $13$.  This gives a series of 12 numbers.  We alternate these into two alternate series, eg

$$c(n) = cis(2\pi n/13)$$
$$S1 = c(1)+c(4)+c(3)+c(12)+c(9)+c(10)$$
$$S2 = c(2)+c(8)+c(6)+c(11)+c(5)+c(7)$$

One can see that the subscript in $S2$ is twice that of $S1$, and the subscript of the following term in $S1$ is four times that of the base term.  So $3=4*4 mod 13$, etc.

Now, the isomorphism between $S1$ and $S2$ corresponds to a reversal of sign on a square-root.  There is a therom that the product of numbers $1-c(n)$ for $n$ = 1 to p-1, gives p (here $p=13$), so the square root here is that $13 = (6-S1)*(6-S2)$.  This works for all primes.

It should be noted that $6-S1$ is not exactly $\sqrt{13}$, but something that involves this prime, like $(13+3 \sqrt{13})/2$ or similar.