# Problem with roots of unity

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields

Let $\zeta$ a root of $x^{p}-1$, with $p$ an odd prime, and $K$ a subgroup of the mutiplicative group $\mathbb{Z}_p^{*}$ of index $2$. I need to prove that

$a=\displaystyle\sum_{k\in K}\zeta^{k}$

Satisfy $a^{2}+a=(p-1)/4$   if $p\equiv 1\pmod 4$ and
$a^{2}+a=-(p+1)/4$   if $p\equiv 3\pmod 4$ (i have edited this part, now is correct)

Comment: What is your progress?

Comment: The progress is that, actually i had to find $a^{2}+a$ i figure out that, but i need to prove it. But i have seen (just now) that this is related with Quadratic Gauss sums, but now still have to prove that

Comment: I suppose you mean for $\zeta$ to be a primitive root of $x^p-1$?

Comment: Yes, $\zeta$ is a root of $x^{p}-1$

Comment: But do you mean for it to be a *primitive* root? Put differently, do you allow $\zeta = 1$, or must $\zeta$ be one of the other roots?

Comment: sorry, yes i mean a primitive root of the unity (so different to $1$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ is cyclic, the subgroup $K$ of index $2$ is unique and consists of non-zero squares. We get the non-zero squares twice ($x^2=(-x)^2$), so
$$
2a+1=\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}\zeta^{k^2}.
$$
Therefore
$$
(2a+1)^2=\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}\sum_{\ell=0}^{p-1}\zeta^{k^2+\ell^2}.
$$
Let us try and determine how many times a given exponent $x\in\mathbb{F}_p$ appears here.
Denote that number by $N(x)$. It is the number of solutions of the equation
$k^2+\ell^2=x$ with $k,\ell$ ranging over all of $\mathbb{F}_p$.

It will turn out that the value of $N(x)$ depends on whether $p\equiv 1\pmod4$ or
$p\equiv 3\pmod4$. In the former case we have $N(0)=2p-1$, and $N(x)=p-1$ when $x\neq0$.
In the latter case we have $N(0)=1$ and $N(x)=p+1$. Furthermore, we know that
$$
S=\sum_{n=0}^{p-1}\zeta^n=0,
$$
as this is a full period of a geometric sum repeating after $p$ terms.

Therefore we get
$$
(2a+1)^2=\begin{cases}p\zeta^0+(p-1)S=p,&\text{if }\ p\equiv1\pmod4\cr
-p+(p+1)S=-p,&\text{if }\ p\equiv3\pmod4.\cr\end{cases}
$$

As $(2a+1)^2=4a^2+4a+1=4(a^2+a)+1$ your claim follows from this.

I'm fairly sure that the proof for the stated result about the numbers $N(x)$ is in e.g. Ireland & Rosen. Trying to recall how it goes. Anyway, this is a basic result about quadratic Gauss sums.

---

If $a\in\mathbb{F}_p^*$ we clearly have $N(x)=N(a^2x)$, because $(k,\ell)\mapsto (ak,a\ell)$ is a bijection from one set of solutions to the other. Therefore $N(x)=N(kx)$
for all $k\in K$, and we are left with three unknowns $N(0)$, $N(k), k\in K$ and $N(k'),k'\notin K$. We select $1$ to represent elements of $K$ and let $q\notin K$ be a fixed quadratic non-residue.

Assume first that $p\equiv1\pmod4$. Then we know that $-1\in K$, and $-1=i^2$ for some $i\in\mathbb{F}_p$. We have $k^2+\ell^2=0$ if and only if $k=\pm i\ell$. Therefore in this case we get $N(0)=2p-1$ - one solution is $(k,\ell)=(0,0)$ and the other $2(p-1)$ are $(\pm i\ell, \ell)$ with $\ell\neq0$. Let us then determine $N(1)$. If we replace $\ell$ with $i\ell$ we might as well look at the number of solutions of $k^2-\ell^2=1$ or $(k-\ell)(k+\ell)=1$. Here we can let $k-\ell=a$ be an arbitrary non-zero element $a\in\mathbb{F}_p^*$ and we can then solve $k+\ell=1/a$. This linear system determines the pair $(k,\ell)$ uniquely, so there are $p-1$ such pairs. Therefore $N(1)=p-1$, and $N(k)=p-1$ for all $k\in K$. As we have $p^2$ pairs $(k,\ell)$ altogether, we have
$$
p^2=N(0)+|K| N(1)+|K| N(q),
$$
we can solve for $N(q)$ and find that $N(q)=p-1$ as well.

In the case $p\equiv 3\pmod4$ we know that $-1\notin K$. Therefore $k^2+\ell^2=0$ only, if
$k=\ell=0$. So in this case $N(0)=1$. One of seeing that $N(x)=p+1$ for all $x\neq 0$ is to observe that in this case $k^2+\ell^2$ is the norm of the element $k+i\ell$ from $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}^*$. Here $i^2=-1$ and $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}=\mathbb{F}_p[i]$. The cyclicity of the group $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}^*$ together with the fact that the norm is just $(p+1)^{th}$ power then gives the claim. Another way would be to use the quadratic character. I'm fairly sure that there is a similar more elementary argument like the one in $p\equiv1\pmod4$ case, but I can't reproduce it now.

Comment: Thanks very much, i was hoping that i could find an "easy" solution by my own, but i guess is not gonna happen. Anyway your answer was excellent, thanks again

Comment: You could have found it on your own, when only not everybody here immedately posts complete solutions ...

Comment: @Martin, yeah, on another day I would have just said: "Look up quadratic Gauss sums." Today was not that day. May be it was because the comments gave me the impression that not everybody agreed what the question was?

Comment: @Dimitri: The calculation is much easier for a concrete prime. Look up my answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/299409/11619) for $p=7$. And this really is a textbook example from many a book on number theory. I'm not happy with this, because an easier answer is out there. May be you should not have accepted this one?

Comment: Yes i know, i have made some examples, but i couldn´t find a simpler proof, but i liked your answer, and is the easiest proof i have by now