# A group of order 21 has conjugacy classes of sizes 1, 3, 3, 7, and 7, and it has a normal subgroup of order 7. Find its character table.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, normal-subgroups

I’m trying to find the character table of a group of order 21 with conjugacy classes of sizes 1, 3, 3, 7, and 7, and a normal subgroup of order 7.

I’m really confused because I’ve only ever been taught how to find character tables of symmetric groups, so I don’t really know where to start with this group.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/970660/character-table-of-the-non-abelian-group-of-order-21?rq=1