# What are the subfields of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_7)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Let $\zeta = e^{\frac{2i\pi}{7}}$.  I know that the automorphisms of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$ are isomorphic to the cyclic group with $6$ elements so that the subfields of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$ correspond to the subgroups of $C_6$.  I found one of the proper subfields is $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta + \zeta^2 + \zeta^4)$.  I was able to determine this by observing the form of the elements that are fixed by the mapping that takes $\zeta$ to $\zeta^2$.  How can I determine the other subfield that corresponds to the group of $2$ automorphisms consisting of the trivial mapping and the mapping that sends $\zeta$ to $\zeta^6$?

Comment: Note that $\zeta^6 = \zeta^{-1}$, so $\zeta + \zeta^6$ is invariant under your map.

Comment: @Magdiragdag Thanks  I agree with the above statement but I do not understand how this will help me determine the subfield.

Comment: In exactly the same way as you determined the other subfield: there you found the element $\zeta + \zeta^2 + \zeta^4$ that is invariant under the map $\zeta \mapsto \zeta^2$ and hence the field ${\mathbb Q}(\zeta + \zeta^2 + \zeta^4$) is the field corresponding to the subgroup $C_3$ of $C_6$.

Comment: What Magdiragdag says! Also, [in this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/299417/11619) I give a more familiar description for the quadratic subfield that you found.

Comment: I think that the elements of Q(zeta) that are fixed by this mapping that takes zeta to zeta^6 must have the form a + b(zeta^2 + zeta^5) + c(zeta^3 + zeta^4) for some a,b,c in Q.  So is the other field: Q( zeta^2 + zeta^5, zeta^3 + zeta^4) ) ?

Comment: Geoffrey, you can also just use the element $u=\zeta+\zeta^{-1}=2\cos(2\pi/7)$ that Magdiragdag suggested. Observe that $u^2=\zeta^2+2+\zeta^5$ and
$$u^3=\zeta^3+3\zeta+3\zeta^{-1}+\zeta^{-3},$$ so $u^3-3u=\zeta^3+\zeta^4$.

Comment: Let z = e^(2*Pi*I/5).  I have that the only proper subfield (other than Q) of Q(z) is Q(z^2 + z^3) = Q(sqrt(5)).  Does anyone agree?

Answer (score 0):

1. **Basis Information:**

   - $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_7)$ is obtained by adjoining a primitive 7th root of unity, denoted as $\zeta_7$, to the rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$.
2. **Galois Group:**

   - The Galois group of the extension is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_7^*$, the multiplicative group of integers modulo 7.
3. **Identifying Subgroups:**

   - The subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_7^*$ are $\{1\}, \{1, 2, 4\}, \{1, 3, 5, 2, 6, 4\}, \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$
4. **Fixed Fields:**

   - Corresponding to each subgroup, we find the fixed fields under the action of the Galois group.
5. **Subfield 1: $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_7)$:**

   - The full field extension $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_7)$.
6. **Subfield 2: $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_7 + \zeta_7^{-1})$:**

   - The fixed field under complex conjugation, which is represented by the subgroup $\{1\}$.
7. **Subfield 3: $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_7 + \zeta_7^2 + \zeta_7^4)$:**

   - The fixed field under a cyclic subgroup of order $3$, represented by $\{1, 2, 4\}$.
8. **Subfield 4: $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_7^3)$:**

   - The fixed field under a cyclic subgroup of order 2, represented by $\{1, 3, 5, 2, 6, 4\}$.

These subfields correspond to distinct intermediate field extensions between $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_7)$ and are determined by the fixed elements under specific subgroups of the Galois group.