# Determining the degree of a root of unity over a cyclotomic expansion

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field, cyclotomic-polynomials

> For $\xi_{n} = e^{2\pi i/n}$ , determine the degree of $\xi_{7}$ over the field $\Bbb{Q}(\xi_{3})$.

How would I approach this problem? I'm having trouble starting this problem and can't find any resources that could help me. Any help will be great, thanks.

Comment: Are you allowed to use Galois Theory?

Comment: Depending on how much you know about cyclotomic fields the observation $\Bbb{Q}(\xi_3,\xi_7)=\Bbb{Q}(\xi_{21})$ may or may not help.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, you are allowed to use Galois Theory

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen $\Bbb{Q}(\xi_{21})$ has order 21 over $Q$, do I use that piece of info?

Comment: Err [check a few facts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_field) first. Then you can use that piece of info.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Oops, I meant order 20. Is that right?

Comment: $\phi(21)=?????$ But I 'm redacting my suggestion to the extent that answering your question is more or less equivalent to proving the dimension formula for cyclotomic extensions of the rationals in this case. A lower brow approach is to be preferred.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you for the help

Answer (score 3):

Extended hints:

1. You probably know that $[\Bbb{Q}(\xi_7):\Bbb{Q}]=6$ and $[\Bbb{Q}(\xi_3):\Bbb{Q}]=2$, so you can deduce (how?) that the desired degree is either $3$ or $6$. The former case can happen only, if $\xi_3\in\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_7)$.
2. The Galois group $G=Gal(\Bbb{Q}(\xi_7):\Bbb{Q})\simeq\Bbb{Z}_7^*$ is cyclic of order six. Therefore, by Galois correspondence, it has a *unique* subfield of degree two.
3. By [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/299417/11619) (or many others) we see that $\sqrt{-7}\in \Bbb{Q}(\xi_7)$, so the unique quadratic subfield of $\Bbb{Q}(\xi_7)$ is $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-7})$.
4. So if you can show that $\xi_3\notin \Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-7})$, then it follows that $\xi_3\notin \Bbb{Q}(\xi_7)$, and you are done.