# $p$ is an odd prime, $z$ is a primitive $p$th root of 1. Prove that $\mathbb{Q}(z)$ contains the field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{(-1)^{\frac {p-1}{2}}p})$

Tags: number-theory, field-theory

I was hoping someone could help me solve the following exercise:

> Let $p$ be an odd prime, and let $z$ be a primitive $p$th root of 1. Prove that $\mathbb{Q}(z)$ contains the field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{(-1)^{\frac {p-1}{2}}p})$

Thanks in advance, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use the fact that the quadratic subfield only ramifies at $p$, or quadratic Gauss sums, or search this website for an answer.

Comment: [Gauss sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_Gauss_sum)

Comment: How were you "hoping someone could help you" if you give zero indication about your background and how you tried to solve this? After 20+ months on the site, you are still not following the drill?

Comment: I'm self studying fields and Galois theory, and I'm quite stuck on this question.

Comment: In that case I very much recommend that you look up Gauss sums. [Here's the case $p=7$ spelled out](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/299417/11619)