# minimal polynomial of $\sin (2\pi/7)$ over $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 7)$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, minimal-polynomials, cyclotomic-polynomials

How to find the minimal polynomial of $\sin (2\pi/7)$ over $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 7)$ ? And the minimal polynomial of $\sin (2\pi/11)$ over $\mathbb Q(\sqrt {11})$  ?

I know that the minimal polynomial of $\sin (2\pi/7)$ over $\mathbb Q$ is $\dfrac 1{64} (64x^6-112x^4+56x^2-7)$ , but what is the minimal polynomial over $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 7)$ ?

Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything happens inside the field $L=\Bbb{Q}(\zeta,i)$, where $\zeta=e^{2\pi i/7}$. The field $K=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{7})$ is a subfield of $L$.
This implies that the question can be answered by applying Galois theory. See below.

The extension $L/\Bbb{Q}$ is Galois as a compositum of the seventh cyclotomic field and the quadratic extension $\Bbb{Q}(i)$. Therefore $Gal(L/\Bbb{Q})\simeq C_6\times C_2$.
Any automorphism is uniquely determined by where it maps $\zeta$ and $i$, and all the twelve possible combinations occur.

Because (check out Gauss sums or [look at this old answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/299417/11619))
$$
\zeta+\zeta^2+\zeta^4=\frac{-1+i\sqrt7}2
$$
we can write 
$$
\sqrt7=-2i(\zeta+\zeta^2+\zeta^4)-i.
$$
As $\overline{\zeta+\zeta^2+\zeta^4}=\zeta^3+\zeta^5+\zeta^6$ it follows that $\sqrt7$ is stable under the automorphism $\sigma$ defined by $\sigma(i)=-i$,
$\sigma(\zeta)=\zeta^3$. Because the restriction of $\sigma$ to $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta)$ has order six, so does $\sigma$. Therefore we can conclude that
$$
Gal(L/K)=\langle\sigma\rangle\simeq C_6.
$$

What this means is that the $K$-conjugates of $u=2\sin(2\pi/7)=-i(\zeta-\zeta^{-1})$ are
$$
\sigma(u)=i(\zeta^3-\zeta^{-3})=-2\sin(6\pi/7)
$$
and
$$
\sigma^2(u)=-i(\zeta^9-\zeta^{-9})=2\sin(4\pi/7).
$$
As an extra exercise you are invited to verify that $\sigma^3(u)=u$.

Therefore the minimal polynomial of $u$ over $K$ is the cubic
$$
m(x)=(x-2\sin(2\pi/7))(x+2\sin(6\pi/7))(x-2\sin(4\pi/7)).
$$
Also leaving it to you to crunch out those sums of powers of $\zeta$ and $i$, and to prove that
$$
m(x)=x^3-\sqrt7 x^2+\sqrt7\in K[x].
$$
Getting the minimal polynomial of $u/2$ from here is, of course, trivial.

Comment: To get the minimal polynomial of $\sin(2\pi/11)$ over $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{11})$ you can similarly work with the automorphisms of $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{11},i)$.

Comment: But, I'm somewhat unhappy with this. Somehow I suspect a useful known trig identity can be located... Making those heavy calculations with roots of unity in the end unnecessary? :-(

Comment: Doesn't your $\sigma (u)$ has a sign typo ... shouldn't $i$ be mapped to $-i$ ?

Comment: Thanks @users. Both $\sigma(u)$ and $\sigma^2(u)$ had the wrong sign in their first forms (but were correct when written as values of sine.