# Help understanding the question

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, finite-fields

Q) Let $\zeta = e^{\frac{2\pi i}{11}}$. Find a quadratic equation over $Q$ for $x = \sum_{a\in Q}\zeta^a$, where $Q \subset \mathbb{Z}_{11}^{*}$ is the set of squares in $\mathbb{Z}_{11}^{*}$.

Does this mean $Q = \{1,4,9\}$ and I have to find a quadratic function over $Q$ ($3^3$ such functions are possible) such that $x = \sum_{a\in Q}\zeta^a$ is a root of the quadratic function in some extension of $Q$? If yes, can you please suggest where I can start? Thanks and appreciate a hint.

Comment: $4^2 = 5$ in $\mathbb{Z_{11}}$. What about it?

Comment: and $5^2\equiv3\pmod{11}$

Comment: This isn't relevant to other people on the stack exchange, but I'm pretty sure we're in the same class. If I'm right, our professor posted a pdf with examples on canvas. Look in the announcements for "handout on square roots of primes."

Comment: @asterac Indeed we are! Thanks for pointing out the handout, that was helpful.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_Gauss_sum

Comment: What reuns says! [Here's](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/299417/11619) how the calculations go in the case $p=7$. Yours is the case $p=11$, and that can still be done by hand in the same way - there will just be more terms! Sorry about blowing my own trumpet to this extent.