# Evaluate sum roots of unity $\zeta_{17}+\zeta_{17}^{-1}+\zeta_{17}^{2}+\zeta_{17}^{-2}+\zeta_{17}^{4}+\zeta_{17}^{-4}+\zeta_{17}^{8}+\zeta_{17}^{-8}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, roots, cyclotomic-fields

For $\zeta_{17}$ a primitive $17^{\text{th}}$ root of unity, I need to reduce $\zeta_{17}+\zeta_{17}^{-1}+\zeta_{17}^{2}+\zeta_{17}^{-2}+\zeta_{17}^{4}+\zeta_{17}^{-4}+\zeta_{17}^{8}+\zeta_{17}^{-8}$ into a simpler form. I believe it should be an integer actually. I just can't work it out, even using complex exponentials. There must be a trick I don't know about.

Comment: The exponents are all the quadratic residues modulo $17$. So, by Galois theory, the sum is, indeed, an element of a quadratic field. Let $S$ be your sum. Compute $S^2$. You can write it in terms of $S$ and an integer using the minimal polynomial of $\zeta_{17}$. Then you have a quadratic equation and can solve for $S$.

Comment: Lol, I'm actually building that minimal polynomial. This would be the coefficient of degree 1

Comment: I used the (standard) idea [in this old answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/299417/11619). Then the root of unity was of order seven. You have seventeen, so you get a little bit more tems, but the principle is the same.

Comment: The minimal polynomial of $\zeta_{17}$ reads $$\sum_{j=-8}^8\zeta_{17}^j=0.$$ When you calculate $S^2$, the missing exponents also appear.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you take for $S$?

Comment: You take the above thing you want to reduce as $S$. Don't worry when you calculate $S^2$, because you can see a pattern in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a=\frac\pi{17}$ and

$$\begin{align}
& S = \cos2a+\cos4a+\cos8a+\cos16a \\
& T = \cos6a+\cos10a+\cos12a+\cos14a \\
\end{align} $$

Then, we have
$$\zeta_{17}+\zeta_{17}^{-1}+\zeta_{17}^{2}+\zeta_{17}^{-2}+\zeta_{17}^{4}+\zeta_{17}^{-4}+\zeta_{17}^{8}+\zeta_{17}^{-8}=2S$$

Evaluate
$$\begin{align}
& 2\sin a( S+T )\\
&  = 2\sin a( \cos2a+\cos4a+\cos6a+\cos8a+\cos10a+\cos12a+\cos14a+\cos16a ) \\
&  = \sin17a-\sin a = 0-\sin a = -\sin a \\
\end{align}$$

which leads to
$$S+T= -\frac12$$

On the other hand, it can also be evaluated, albeit more involved, that

$$ST = -1$$

Therefore, $S$ satisfies the quadratic equation

$$S^2+\frac12S-1=0$$

which yields $S=\frac{\sqrt{17}-1}4$. Thus,

$$\zeta_{17}+\zeta_{17}^{-1}+\zeta_{17}^{2}+\zeta_{17}^{-2}+\zeta_{17}^{4}+\zeta_{17}^{-4}+\zeta_{17}^{8}+\zeta_{17}^{-8}=\frac{\sqrt{17}-1}2$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\zeta_{17}+\zeta_{17}^{-1}+\zeta_{17}^{2}+\zeta_{17}^{-2}+\zeta_{17}^{4}+\zeta_{17}^{-4}+\zeta_{17}^{8}+\zeta_{17}^{-8}=a$ and

$\zeta_{17}^3+\zeta_{17}^{-3}+\zeta_{17}^{5}+\zeta_{17}^{-5}+\zeta_{17}^{6}+\zeta_{17}^{-6}+\zeta_{17}^{7}+\zeta_{17}^{-7}=b.$

Thus, $$a+b+1=0$$ and calculate $ab$.

I got $$ab=-4.$$

Now, easy to check that $a>0$, which since $$a^2+a-4=0,$$ gives $$a=\frac{-1+\sqrt{17}}{2}.$$