# Introduction to De Moivre's theorem

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, fractions

> If $a=\cos\frac{2π}7+i\sin\frac{2π}7$, $b=a+a^2+a^4$, $c=a^3+a^5+a^6$, show that $b$ and $c$ are the roots of the equation $x^2+x+2=0$.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/ for advice on how to effectively format your questions.

Comment: Though I can not read your question, I can see you have shown no effort so far. Try showing some effort so that we can help you figure out where you went wrong.

Comment: Now add what you have tried so far.

Comment: **Hint:** Substituting $a = e^{\frac{2 \iota \pi}7}$  _might_ help.

Comment: take $e^{2i\pi/7}$ as a  where a  is 7th root of unity

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1895204/help-with-this-trigonometry-problem

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Note that

$$a=\cos\frac{2π}7+i\sin\frac{2π}7=e^{\frac{2πi}7}$$

thus

$$1+a+a^2+a^3+a^4+a^5+a^6=0$$
[Proof that sum of complex unit roots is zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/891875/proof-that-sum-of-complex-unit-roots-is-zero)

Comment: +1 for providing the basic idea to the OP rather than solving it

Comment: ops...sorry for the typo, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$$b+c=\cos\frac{2\pi}{7}+\cos\frac{4\pi}{7}+\cos\frac{8\pi}{7}+\left(\sin\frac{2\pi}{7}+\sin\frac{4\pi}{7}+\sin\frac{8\pi}{7}\right)i+$$
$$+\cos\frac{6\pi}{7}+\cos\frac{10\pi}{7}+\cos\frac{12\pi}{7}+\left(\sin\frac{6\pi}{7}+\sin\frac{10\pi}{7}+\sin\frac{12\pi}{7}\right)i=$$
$$=\cos\frac{2\pi}{7}+\cos\frac{4\pi}{7}+\cos\frac{6\pi}{7}+\cos\frac{6\pi}{7}+\cos\frac{4\pi}{7}+\cos\frac{2\pi}{7}+$$
$$+\left(\sin\frac{2\pi}{7}+\sin\frac{4\pi}{7}-\sin\frac{6\pi}{7}+\sin\frac{6\pi}{7}-\sin\frac{4\pi}{7}-\sin\frac{2\pi}{7}\right)i=$$
$$=\frac{2\sin\frac{\pi}{7}\cos\frac{2\pi}{7}+2\sin\frac{\pi}{7}\cos\frac{4\pi}{7}+2\sin\frac{\pi}{7}\cos\frac{6\pi}{7}}{2\sin\frac{\pi}{7}}=$$
$$=\frac{\sin\frac{3\pi}{7}-\sin\frac{\pi}{7}+\sin\frac{5\pi}{7}-\sin\frac{3\pi}{7}+\sin\frac{7\pi}{7}-\sin\frac{5\pi}{7}}{2\sin\frac{\pi}{7}}=-1.$$
You can calculate the value of $ab$ by the same way.

Indeed, since we proved that $$\cos\frac{2\pi}{7}+\cos\frac{4\pi}{7}+\cos\frac{6\pi}{7}=-\frac{1}{2},$$ we obtain:
$$bc=\left(-\frac{1}{2}+\left(\sin\frac{2\pi}{7}+\sin\frac{4\pi}{7}+\sin\frac{8\pi}{7}\right)i\right)\left(-\frac{1}{2}-\left(\sin\frac{2\pi}{7}+\sin\frac{4\pi}{7}+\sin\frac{8\pi}{7}\right)i\right)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{4}+\left(\sin\frac{2\pi}{7}+\sin\frac{4\pi}{7}-\sin\frac{6\pi}{7}\right)^2=$$
$$=\tfrac{1}{4}+\sin^2\frac{2\pi}{7}+\sin^2\frac{4\pi}{7}+\sin^2\frac{6\pi}{7}+2\sin\frac{2\pi}{7}\sin\frac{4\pi}{7}-2\sin\frac{2\pi}{7}\sin\frac{6\pi}{7}-2\sin\frac{4\pi}{7}\sin\frac{6\pi}{7}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\cos\frac{4\pi}{7}+1-\cos\frac{6\pi}{7}+1-\cos\frac{2\pi}{7}\right)+$$
$$+\cos\frac{2\pi}{7}-\cos\frac{6\pi}{7}+\cos\frac{6\pi}{7}-\cos\frac{4\pi}{7}+\cos\frac{4\pi}{7}-\cos\frac{2\pi}{7}=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{7}{4}=2$$
and use the Vieta's theorem.

Also, we can use De Moivre here.

$a^7=\cos2\pi+i\sin2\pi=1$ and since $a\neq1$, we obtain:
$$a^6+a^5+a^4+a^3+a^2+a+1=0,$$ which gives $b+c=-1.$

Now, $$bc=a^4(1+a+a^3)(1+a^2+a^3)=a^4(a^6+a^5+a^4+3a^3+a^2+a+1)=2a^7=2$$ and we are done again.

Comment: nice way, original as usual!

Comment: Would you present this solution to your students after introducing the topic of roots of unity?

Comment: @uniquesolution ago Yes of course. I added something. See now.

Comment: You are welcome!